# iPhone motion detection in idle mode

Tags: iphone

I'd like my audio recorder app to react to accelerometer events while in idle mode. 
Audio capturing works fine during idle mode, but my motion detection code never gets called, once the app enters in idle mode.

Is it possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can suggest is you must stop the application from being enter into idle mode..

And after certain interval of time manually put the application in idle by dimming its light and doing the code for unlocking...

Then you can do whatever you want...